# How I can Convert Csv file to parquet file using java I've used df.write().parquet but got the following error?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, parquet

```
package com.evampsaanga.imran.testing;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class ReadingCsv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Text File Data Load").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.host","localhost").set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000");       
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate(); 
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat")
                .option("sep", ",")
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("header", true)
                .load("E:/CarsData.csv");
    df.write().parquet("test.parquet");
```

**I have used df.write.parquet but I am getting this error**

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for parquet (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.parquet.ParquetDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:702)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:728)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:948)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:269)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:829)
> at com.evampsaanga.imran.testing.ReadingCsv.main(ReadingCsv.java:23)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while read or write Parquet format data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579754/error-while-read-or-write-parquet-format-data)